# ActionBar with AppCompat actionBarItemBackground not working

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to change the color of an item when it pressed. I used the `actionBarItemBackground` item in the action bar style, but nothing happens.. The color not changed...

Here my code:

```
<style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle.Title</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground" tools:ignore="NewApi">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
</style>
```

And the selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_item" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_item" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

And the drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

What is worng? Someone?

Answer (score 1):

`actionBarItemBackground` isn't inherit of `Widget.ActionBar`. You should be placing it in your root theme, wherever you apply your `ActionBarStyle`, but not *in* your `ActionBarStyle`. So, something like:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground" tools:ignore="NewApi">@drawable/action_bar_item_selector</item>
</style>
```